# Open json file from outside of python directory

Tags: python, json, directory

I am trying to open the JSON file `original.json` that is outside of my working directory `excelTest.py`: [image: Directory]

- `excelTest.py` is in /Documents/Coding projects/pwdemo/pwdemo
- `original.json` is in /Documents/Coding projects/pwdemo

So I've tried to do:

```
with open("../original.json", 'r') as json_file:
      json_data = json.load(json_file)
```

but I get the following error: `No such file or directory: '../original.json'`

Comment: try `with open("./original.json", 'r') as json_file:`

Answer (score 1):

You can `pip install from-root` and then use the from_root function like this:

```
import json

from from_root import from_root

with open(from_root('original.json'), 'r') as json_file:
      json_data = json.load(json_file)
```

Comment: I get the following error when trying this: "raise FileNotFoundError(
FileNotFoundError: There is neither ".git" directory nor ".project-root" file, cannot detect root folder. Initialize a git repository or create an empty ".project-root" file in the project root"

Comment: When from_root is called, folders in the current traceback are looked through one by one in order to find .git directory or .project-root file (might be empty; you have to create it on your own). The first one that contains at least one of them are considered as a root directory.

There is a special case. If your package was installed by someone else via, for example, pip, the root directory is the one that is next to site-packages so there will be no conflicts with your usages of from-root and your users' ones

Comment: But honestly your original answer should work just fine. Maybe you're doing something wrong.